# Returning a View in a new window from the controllers MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to receive the post of the submit in a new window

```
<input class="btnText" id="PreviewURL" value="Preview" type="submit" />
```

and in jQuery I have this

```
$('#PreviewURL').click(function () {
  $('#IsPreview').val(true);
  window.open(this.href);
});
```

when the controller return his view, instead of open it in a new window, open it opens in the same one, and the new window appear empty

what can I do?

Comment: not clear with question. can you elaborate what you want

Answer (score 0):

Opening a new window with `this.href` is going to perform a get on the href you are sending.  If you have to `POST` the data then you might be best off opening a new page and passing it the parameters you need in the query string and when that page loads have it perform an AJAX post and load that into its own content.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, with this function it work perfectly,

`$('#PreviewURL').click(function () {
document.forms["articleForm"].action = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "Action";
document.forms["articleForm"].target = "_blank";});`